# Not able to create new color item in colors.xml file

Tags: android, xml, colors

The error I am getting is : **"The color "colorRed" in values has no declaration in the base values folder; this can lead to crashes when the resource is queried in a configuration that does not match this qualifier less... "**

I have tried clean project and rebuild and also tried invalidate cache & restart but still that error not going.

I have attached screenshot of colors.xml file

[image]

Comment: why all the color names has error? are they being repeated or what?

Comment: That's what I am thinking. And they are not repeated they are all  unique names, even if I delete all those and create new name it is giving the same error but i am not getting error for those first 5 name.

Comment: @GowthamanM already tired but no luck, still the error is there.

Comment: If you are placing the cursor above the red line it should give the reason for the error. Also did you tried running the app?. From what I can see is the colors are loaded correctly because it's showing the preview in side.

Comment: @sunilsunny "The color "colorRed" in values has no declaration in the base values folder; this can lead to crashes when the resource is queried in a configuration that does not match this qualifier less..." this is what the reason is coming when i place cursor on it.

Comment: have you initialized "colorRed" in colors.xml?

Comment: You're using **underscore** which is creating problems in the code. Try replacing **underscore** color names by using `CamelNotation`

Comment: @SushantPaudel it works with underscore also because i am already using these same colors in other application. I don't think underscore will create problem.

Comment: @KrishnaCh will you add the error shown by the IDE while hovering on the red underline.

Comment: @SushantPaudel this is the error i'm getting **The color "colorRed" in values has no declaration in the base values folder; this can lead to crashes when the resource is queried in a configuration that does not match this qualifier less...**

Comment: Is this word "colorRed" change to "title" if you are placing cursor over title?.

Comment: @sunilsunny Yes! it is changing.

Comment: what happens if you are cutting color "title" and pasting in between "colorWhite" and "colorAccent" ?. Also may be it's just a studio bug and you may able to run the app. Are you able to run the app ?.

Comment: @sunilsunny yeah i have tried, it not giving any error if copy that color code and paste it in **colorWhite** and its the app is running.

Comment: If the app is running you can just ignore it.. It may be an Android Studio glitch.

Comment: @sunilsunny you are missing a point, app is running when i replace the **colorWhite** but its not running and giving error when i create new color name

Comment: ok .Then I have no idea. I have never experienced with this error.

Comment: @sunilsunny Okay, Thank you.

Comment: I had this exact same error.  The colors.xml file I modified WAS in the base values folder.  I restarted Android Studio, and it went away.  I'm using Android Studio 3.2 Canary 14.  It appears to be a bug.  I've experience other resource problems in the this Canary version too.

Comment: @metaphyze thanks for you response, I tried the about method and it worked but that error is coming again when i add new color.

Comment: Just renaming the item name value and then undoing it worked for me...

Comment: I tried other answers, it did not work. I build the app, it worked fine. No invalidate, no restart.

Answer (score 189, accepted):

I solved the problem cleaning the project and build it again. If it doesn't work, invalidate caches and restart.

I'm using Android Studio 3.2

Invalidate Caches with File > Invalidate Caches / Restart... > Invalidate and Restart

[image]
[image]

Comment: Invalidate Caches with File > Invalidate Caches / Restart... > Invalidate and Restart

Comment: Happened for dimens.xml and this is the only solution that worked.

Comment: It is not practical to `Invalidate Cache and Restart` every time a new color is added to the colors file.
Please suggest alternatives.

Comment: For those who stumbled across this issue: For me, a simple restart of Android Studio was sufficient.

Comment: It still occurs with Android Studio Flamingo | 2022.2.1 Patch 2 (Build #AI-222.4459.24.2221.10121639, built on May 12, 2023). Close and reopen Android Studio to fix

Comment: @Amar Jain I don't think there's an alternative. It is annoying and yucky, but I'd say it's practical since the alternative is you can't add new values. If you have several to add, add them all and then invalidate/restart.

Answer (score 79):

Its a bug, and it happens for dimensions and possibly others. (Not just colours.) First time I saw it was the day I upgraded to AS 3.2.1.

But you *may **not** need* to clean, rebuild or invalidate caches. Try this:

(A) Cut and save (e.g. to NotePad) the flagged XML from the base folder and all qualified folders.
(B) Paste it back in, starting with the base folder

**Update: 10Jan2019** [Dumb and dumber]

In fact, not even cutting and pasting is necessary. Suppose the following line is giving the problem...

```
<string name="edit">Edit</string>
```

Just change the tag to anything. e.g.

```
<xstring name="edit">Edit</string>
```

Then wait a second for removal to occur before changing it back

Comment: You don't even need to cut and save. Just Ctrl + X, then Ctrl + V usually fixes it.

Comment: This is the fastest solution

Comment: Anybody found a final solution to this problem? I may sound lazy but I actually got tired of having to Ctrl + X, Ctrl + V everytime I start / restart Android Studio...

Comment: @Andrei Meșină What Android Studio version are you using?

Comment: @BadLoser The latest version, 3.3.2

Comment: I just reproduced it. THANKFULLY this project is tiny. Otherwise it would be crazy. I had to go through `dimens`, `strings`, `colors`, and `layouts` - put an "X" in the id string and remove it.

Comment: LOL I just noticed "asked 11 months ago". HAHA only 24 months to go until the fix.3 years for the win.

Comment: Update: Tried everything Ctrl + X, then Ctrl + V  or Ctrl + A, Ctrl + X, then Ctrl + V , but only Restart and Invalid cache fixed it.

Answer (score 21):

It's a weird bug. but here's a Workaround:
Open the file in android studio and select all the text.
now cut all the text and paste it in the same place.
(or simply, go to the problematic file and press- 'ctrl+A' --> 'ctrl+x' --> 'ctrl+v')
this does not change anything but apparently solves the errors.

Comment: Unbelievable solution.

Answer (score 5):

This error occures still in AS3.4C10... so it is not solved yet.

For me, the only remedy is to select "Invalidate Cache/Restart" from File menu.

RG

Answer (score 4):

Cleaning Project solved my problem

Answer (score 3):

I might be a bit late to the party, but the latest update of Android Studio (v3.2 Canary 17) seems to have solved this bug.

I had a similar issue with colors and resources and updating Studio seems to have fixed it.

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 2):

This is not an error. It is the IDE bug.

Run the project and error will be automatically resolved.

Answer (score 1):

I quit and restarted Studio and the error went away.

Answer (score 1):

It has occurred for me many times. This appears an Android Studio bug to me.

**This may really not be an error though Android Studio shows it temporarily, most likely due to different code in generated files.**

- **Most of the time this error goes if we run build or clean project and rebuild project. Android studio restart is not always required.**
- If that does not work invalidate cache and restart android studio.

This Error can appear for any of xml files. Not just colors. If you see too many errors, it's surely this one. However, sometimes the error occurs even for just one line.  That can be difficult to identify. If you think the error is totally illogical, try a rebuild.
Very rarely I have seen this kind of absurd errors in Kotlin or Java files as well which go away on clean build.

Answer (score 0):

Open Resources->Add new Resource -> choise "New Color value.." other defend on you
I using in android 3.3.1

Answer (score 0):

I'm late to the party, but I fixed this problem by just altering the typing work. I added some more spaces to make it look cleaner and more readable and suddenly the red underline and error messages were gone. Must have been a bug of sorts.
(Studio 3.3.3)

Comment: Yeah, It might be a bug. I have resolved by cleaning the project and restarting it.

Answer (score 0):

I had same error. I just ran the project with same condition and the error went away.

Answer (score 0):

Did you paste it in from a spreadsheet? If so, just check that everything that looks like a double quote is in fact a double quote. Spreadsheets are a great way to build lengthy resource files, concatenating cells of xml formatting text around  cells of names & items etc, but you might find that some of those cells you began with a double quote (e.g. ") will usually have a special open/close-quote character instead. These look like the real thing, but they won't be recognised as xml text indicators, so if e.g. your object name never gets initiated, you'll get this error.

Answer (score 0):

In my case there was literally **"no declaration in the base values folder"** because the xml file wasn't in the base values folder, after selecting create new file, although the directory tree showed it to be in the values folder.

Find your xml file in the directory tree, select refactor, select move, and look at the path.  If there's an invisible addition to the path, delete it back to the proper folder.